# IF Function with multiple true values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Google Sheets has the following IF Function:

IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)

Is it possible to have multiple 'values_if_true' where the formula chooses one of those values randomly? If so, how?

[image: example sheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to select a random value from column B, C or D you can use the INDEX and RANDBETWEEN functions along with an IF

```
=IF(A1=1,INDEX(B1:D1,RANDBETWEEN(1,3)),"")
```

You would then just need to extend the formula to the bottom of your data

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have multiple 'values_if_true'

yes and its called "nesting". example:

```
=IF(A2=1, IF(B2="apple", "x", "y"), "z")
```

further, you may place another nested if-statement instead `x`, `y` or `z`

on your example it is not clear how you want to alternate between `apple`  and `pear` - there are several options (random, predetermined, alternating)